# Blocking access to Tablet win 8.1 OS

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tablet

I have created a WPF Kiosk application. I have got an issue with the app while running in tablet.Swiping from left and right of the screen gives access to win 8.1 OS. That is charms bar and minimized apps appearing while swiping. How we can block this access from win 8.1 OS when running the app ?

Comment: You need to look into [Kiosk Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you are searching for called `Kiosk mode` or `Assigned Access Account`

[Assigned Access](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/assigned-access)